# What was wrong with this question?

Tags: support

The following question got nine downvotes:

[How best to demonstrate that as a software developer you make the company money](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/68209/how-best-to-demonstrate-that-as-a-software-developer-you-make-the-company-money)

Was this the kind of question we want to avoid? If, so why?

In the comments they protest that they are in this situation because they are a good person. Is that bad here?

Is there anything wrong with the question itself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm pretty sure this guy is trolling us.

Comment: What even is trolling if a legitimate question counts as such. Like tears count as a pool of water.

Comment: @AndreiROM I agree.  This joker has a habbit of trolling, then posting in here playing innocent.

Comment: @RichardU What is trolling here? What are the rules? Just disagreement? I nearly died because of workplace decisions. I got angry. People here called it trolling.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter-Poulsen We have a "be nice policy" here.  You are either deliberately trolling, or have extreme difficulty expressing yourself.  I suspect the former.  If I am wrong, I would suggest seeking assistance in improving your online conversational skills.

Comment: @RichardU I like to fix things, people. Most people don't want to be fixed. Or rather they do, but they still hate it when you try.

Comment: This is troll or someone with metal health issues.   He has used foul language in a few comments that have been deleted.   Moderators I hope you are considering a ban.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter-Poulsen This is the best definition I have found for  [Trolling](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayFulltext?type=6&fid=10293504&jid=APA&volumeId=-1&issueId=-1&aid=10293503&bodyId=&membershipNumber=&societyETOCSession=&fulltextType=RA&fileId=S2053447716000099)

Answer (score 9):

For a second I thought you might be a troll, but now I think you're simply desperate for attention.

You describe a situation which is borderline fantasy, reply to our requests for clarification in ways which you must think make you sound deep, and philosophical, but ultimately end up being annoying and uninformative, and fire back with vague BS when people start to call you out.

At best, cherry picking the coherent parts of your posts, you seem to have a serious attitude problem which is leading to you basically being unemployable. (aka you're in a bad situation because you've done it to yourself)

Ultimately this is why people are down-voting: because they're getting confused and frustrated with you. And this very much includes myself at this point.

Comment: It happened. You think... what you like. It still occurred.

Comment: See, this is what I mean. You're not a character in a Shakespeare play. Please express whatever it is you have to say clearly, and concisely.

Comment: "a situation which is borderline fantasy," Yet it happened. Why make me pretend. I say the truth. People here ask me to lie. I refuse.

Comment: No one is asking you to lie - on the contrary. they're asking for the full picture. At this point my understanding of the situation is that you seek to start some kind of worker's revolution in every workplace that hires you. Maybe those workplaces are truly horrible, it's really besides the point.The question you finally ending up asking - and I answered - was all that was truly necessary for your main post. Instead, you initiated a whole conversation about yourself through vague explanations which resulted in a lot of frustration and misunderstandings.

Answer (score 6):

It is down voted as it is just plain not realistic and not clear.  Request for clarification is series of unclear, unrealistic, and inconsistent comments from you.  I would vote to delete if I had the authority.

Comment: Yet all comments are true. At least, all from me. If other people lie should I be responsible? Also the question is true; can a true thing be unrealistic?

Comment: I don't believe you.  Companies fire you then try and rehire at less under a phony name?    Most assertions are just plain unbelievable.  They don't want to accept your changes as they are afraid you will take control of the company?

Comment: yet it did happen. You changed the answer to pretend. Pretending is impossible. The past always exists.

Comment: I don't believe your stories.

Comment: they are true. Are yours?

Comment: I changed "have" to "had".   Anyone can see the edit history.   Yes the past always exists - recollection of the past is another thing.

Comment: Can only hope you are trolling.  Signing off.

Comment: A troll is a false face @Paparazzi. You can find no such here.

Comment: That is your real face is about the only thing I believe from you.  There is a be nice policy and this is going no where.   I cannot be both nice and honest with you.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter-Poulsen I do not find you to be sincere.  Perhaps you have difficulty expressing yourself, but I do not think that is the case.  If I am wrong, then you should seek aid in improving that skill.

Answer (score 6):

I down-voted your question for the following reasons:

- Your question is unclear.
- The details you included are contradictory.
- When you were given feedback from the community, you made no effort
  to improve or edit your question.
- You have demonstrated an complete inability to answer a direct
  question which makes me question your integrity/honesty.

In answer to your questions here:

Yes, this is the kind of question we want to avoid.

No, defending your character in the comments is not BAD, although you can expect the comment to eventually be deleted as comments are temporary in nature.

Yes, there are a number of things wrong with the question as I detailed above.

I feel like your question could potentially be cleaned up such that you could receive some helpful and insightful advice from the community here.  If the question were worded properly, the answer might even be useful to other people.  As things stand at present, neither of those outcomes is likely.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I demonstrate that it will take about a year for me to categorically, and beyond doubt, show that my skills are valuable? Or is this not possible?

Categorically? Beyond a doubt? In about a year?

This is impossible. And it's especially impossible for strangers on the Internet to help you make your case.